# Hashicorp packer script stuck while retrieving autogenerated password

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws, packer, hashicorp, hashicorp-packer

I am using the following packer script to create image using existing windows 2019 server image. But packer always stuck at `Waiting for auto-generated password for instance.` and then eventually stops with error `Timeout waiting for password.`
If I set `winrm_password` to hardcoded password then it skips the step to retrieve password but then it get stuck at connecting to WinRM. I am wondering if `enableWinRM.ps1` script needs to be tweaked for Windows 2019 Server

```
source "amazon-ebs" "windows_server2019" {
  ami_name                              = "${local.name}-${local.timestamp}"
  ami_description                       = "${local.description}"
  communicator                          = "winrm"
  instance_type                         = "t3.medium"
  region                                = "${var.aws_region}"
  vpc_id                                = "vpc-1234556789"
  subnet_id                             = "subnet-123456789"
  temporary_security_group_source_cidrs = ["10.0.0.0/8"]
  winrm_username                        = "Administrator"  
  winrm_use_ssl  = true
  winrm_insecure = true
  user_data_file = "./scripts/enableWinRM.ps1"
  source_ami_filter {
    filters = {
      name = "My-Private-Image-Windows-2019-FULL"
    }
    owners      = ["1234567890"]
    most_recent = true
  }  
}

build {
  name    = local.name
  sources = ["source.amazon-ebs.windows_server2019"]


  provisioner "powershell" {
    elevated_user     = "Administrator"
    elevated_password = build.WinRMPassword
    environment_vars = [
      "AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=${var.aws_region}"
    ]
    scripts = [
      "./scripts/setup.ps1"
    ]
  }

  provisioner "windows-restart" {
    restart_check_command = "powershell -command \"& {Write-Output 'restarted.'}\""
  }

  provisioner "powershell" {
    elevated_user     = "Administrator"
    elevated_password = build.WinRMPassword
    scripts = [
      "./scripts/disableWinRM.ps1"
    ]
  }

  provisioner "powershell" {
    elevated_user     = "Administrator"
    elevated_password = build.WinRMPassword
    inline = [
      "C:\\ProgramData\\Amazon\\EC2-Windows\\Launch\\Scripts\\SendWindowsIsReady.ps1 -Schedule",
      "C:\\ProgramData\\Amazon\\EC2-Windows\\Launch\\Scripts\\InitializeInstance.ps1 -Schedule",
      "C:\\ProgramData\\Amazon\\EC2-Windows\\Launch\\Scripts\\SysprepInstance.ps1 -NoShutdown"
    ]
  }

  post-processor "manifest" {
    output     = "manifest.json"
    strip_path = true
  }
}
```

**enableWinRM.ps1**

```
<powershell>

write-output "Running User Data Script"
write-host "(host) Running User Data Script"

Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Scope LocalMachine -Force -ErrorAction Ignore

# Don't set this before Set-ExecutionPolicy as it throws an error
$ErrorActionPreference = "stop"

# Remove HTTP listener
Remove-Item -Path WSMan:\Localhost\listener\listener* -Recurse

$Cert = New-SelfSignedCertificate -CertstoreLocation Cert:\LocalMachine\My -DnsName "packer"
New-Item -Path WSMan:\LocalHost\Listener -Transport HTTPS -Address * -CertificateThumbPrint $Cert.Thumbprint -Force

# WinRM
write-output "Setting up WinRM"
write-host "(host) setting up WinRM"

cmd.exe /c winrm quickconfig -q
cmd.exe /c winrm set "winrm/config" '@{MaxTimeoutms="1800000"}'
cmd.exe /c winrm set "winrm/config/winrs" '@{MaxMemoryPerShellMB="1024"}'
cmd.exe /c winrm set "winrm/config/service" '@{AllowUnencrypted="true"}'
cmd.exe /c winrm set "winrm/config/client" '@{AllowUnencrypted="true"}'
cmd.exe /c winrm set "winrm/config/service/auth" '@{Basic="true"}'
cmd.exe /c winrm set "winrm/config/client/auth" '@{Basic="true"}'
cmd.exe /c winrm set "winrm/config/service/auth" '@{CredSSP="true"}'
cmd.exe /c winrm set "winrm/config/listener?Address=*+Transport=HTTPS" "@{Port=`"5986`";Hostname=`"packer`";CertificateThumbprint=`"$($Cert.Thumbprint)`"}"
cmd.exe /c netsh advfirewall firewall set rule group="remote administration" new enable=yes
cmd.exe /c netsh firewall add portopening TCP 5986 "Port 5986"
cmd.exe /c net stop winrm
cmd.exe /c sc config winrm start= auto
cmd.exe /c net start winrm

</powershell>
```

Answer (score 0):

The automatic password generation in your configs solved my problem, so I hope I can solve yours!

The one difference in our sources is that I'm specifying the WinRM port. Using your exact enableWinRM.ps1 file, I can successfully create a Windows 2019 image.

```
communicator   = "winrm"
winrm_username = "Administrator"
winrm_use_ssl  = true
winrm_insecure = true
winrm_port     = 5986
```

Comment: yep port was the issue.